# Graph backtrack complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, backtracking

I'm trying to analyse the complexity of backtracking a graph in order to find the longest path.

My algorithm consists of topological sort and then backtrack from each vertex in order to find the longest path.

if it helps, the algorithm is basically: 
    Topological sort(G), for each Vertex calculate the distance to each other vertex
    ,Return the maximum distance

anyway, I don't really know what is the worst case complexity of the backtrack operation.

Any suggestions?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Should we assume that you're only dealing with DAGs, since those are the only graphs that have can be sorted topologically? If that is the case and you're goal actually is finding the longest (simple?) path in the graph, you could just run a shortest path algorithm on the graph after negating all edge weights.

Comment: The graph is also not weighted, and ofc a dag

Comment: If you need help with the complexity of a specific algorithm you wrote, we'll need pseudo code. If you just want an efficient way to find the longest path in a DAG, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths) gives you an O(|V|+|E|) algorithm.